# Why does setting height for the css in my header not force main content down?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to adjust how much my header `(header.php)` "`pushes`" content down on my web page by setting "`height: 100px`" in my CSS. It works in a technical sense... when I Inspect Element in Chrome, the header is indeed `100px` high. But main page content still "floats" up into the header area.

The web page in question is [here](http://shep.ca/rashomon.php).

CSS for the page is pasted [here](http://shortText.com/6c22f024).

There doesn't *seem* to be any CSS associated with the main content page that manually overrides the height of the header's CSS. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how all of this works?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the div is absolutly positioned - remove those css rules and it will work as expected:

```
#headerly {
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* top: 10px; */
    /* right: 10vh; */
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I must be misunderstanding how absolute positioning works -- I thought it could still impact other divs. I'll read up on it again, and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Or just float the container to the right:

```
#headerly {
/* position: absolute; */
float: right;
/* top: 10px; */
/* right: 10vh; */
/* height: 100px; */
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are having this problems because you are working with absolute position, try with relative.